# how to run windows from application c# by pressed key

Tags: c#

i want to run my game when the (ENTER) is pressed by user so how can i make it the game is in c# windows from application ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this ***input_KeyDown*** event on your form it will trigger any keydown on keyboard.

and then use the following code within.

```
private void input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{                        
    if(e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)   
    {  
        //This code will initiated when 
        MessageBox.Show("Pressed enter.");  
    }             
}
```

**OR**
If your Form has AcceptButton defined, you won't be able to use KeyDown event to capture the Enter.

Then use the following code to trigger any Enter Pressed on Form:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if ((this.ActiveControl == myTextBox) && (keyData == Keys.Return))
    {
        //do something
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```